# Angular 2, cannot read from localhost

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have followed the Angular 2 tour of Heroes tutorial to the T, and I have successfully implemented the displaying of the heroes (I renamed them to employees).

However, the tutorial uses an in memory mock web server. When I try to pass a localhost url (that displays json) from my spring-boot backend, I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access
```

However, if I decide to use an online web api, for example :

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Then it works perfectly fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are at least 20 duplicate questions.

Comment: You need to make your API CORS enabled.

Comment: @RavinderKumar Yes, thank you, that was the problem, I added it as a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed duplicate questions (I posted since none of them seemed to have solved my problem). Turns out one of them did put me on the right track. I just had to put

```
@CrossOrigin(origin ="http://localhost:3000")
```

on top of my controller class in Spring. This enabled CORS in spring.

For more details, look here

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework